# Laravel Backpack 4.1.x server Call to a member function hasAccessOrFail() on null error

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm using Laravel backpack 4.1.x with Laravel v7.21.0 locally all the CRUD operations working fine with the development team but after deploying on the server and using license code, then try to use any CRUD operations like listing or create error appearing even though the server and local has the same configuration

```
Call to a member function hasAccessOrFail() on null
```

[create operation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlgDb.png)
[list operation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01MOg.png)
do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: This is very weird Mahmoud - I have never seen this before. Have you customized your CheckIfAdmin.php middleware in any way? Have you overwritten any Backpack PHP classes?

Comment: Are you still having this issue? If so, could you please post your controller code and address the questions tabacitu posed?

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced this problem. Because, I was using constructor in controller which extends the Laravel Backpack CrudController.
But, I forgot to call the parent contorller.

```
class FaqCrudController extends CrudController
{
 public function __construct(EvaluatorInterface $evaluator)
    {
      parent::__construct();
        $this->evaluator = $evaluator;
    }
}
```

Now, it is working.